# Fire a tag when element is loaded on page (Google Tag Manager)

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm using an Element Visibility trigger to track a value that appears on a page. However, I want to track this value even when the user doesn't scroll to the area of the page where the element is (i.e. when the page is loaded, and the value is displayed below the fold, but the user doesn't scroll down there). Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use a DOM ready trigger? The DOM should be available at that point and you can grab the value you want.

Comment: I’ve not setup tags using DOM ready before... I have an ID on the element I want to pull though. Is it possible to use this approach to fire an Event into Google Analytics, that pulls through the Click Text?

Comment: have you found a solution for that? I also have the problem that I want to add a parameter to the dom ready trigger or page loaded trigger

Answer (score 3):

**Suppose that you want to track a value when a certain element is present on the DOM but not depending on the visibility, then there is a 4-steps-way to do it as follows:**

**Assumption**: you know the class or id of the element you are looking for. In the
following example, I will use a class because it allows me to report not just one but a collection of elements being part of the DOM.

1. We can create a trigger to detect every page visited, without any limitations due to the element we want to track could be everywhere.

   [image: Step 1: trigger creation]
2. Then, we can create a TAGS (called "SCRIPT detect element" on the example) of the type "Custom HTML".
   Triggering will be the trigger created in step 1.
   Knowing the class of the element we want to track, the script to write will be:

   ```
   <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    // get all elements with a given class name
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("classname-to-look-for");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
      var evtElementPresent = {
       'event': 'wantedElementRendered'
      }
      // push event per each element.
      window.dataLayer.push(evtElementPresent);
   });
   </script>
   ```

   [image: Step 2: Tag creation]

   *At this point, we will be reporting events (with event `name = "wantedElementRendered"`) from the website to the TAG MANAGER every time an element with the classname equals to `classname-to-look-for` is part of the DOM, despite if it is in the viewport or not.*
3. Now, with that in mind, we need to create a new trigger on TAG MANAGER. This time the type of the trigger will be "Custom Event" and we will make this trigger happen only if the event name is `wantedElementRendered`.

   [image: Step 3: Trigger creation base on custom event]
4. Final step: Let's create a tag that will create a GA4 event reporting it to google analytics.

   - Tag name: "Report X Element is present"
   - Type: "Google Analytics: GA4 Event"
   - Event Name: the name we want to declare on analitycs, eg: "X-Element-Present".
   - Triggering: will be the trigger created on step 3 -> "X Element Rendered".

   [image: Step 4: Tag creation -> GA4 event]

**Now, let's take a look how it works:**

[image: Real example working-a]

[image: Real example working-b]

**Final notes:**

What if we want to track the presence of a lot of elements on the page without taking into account the visibility of each one, but also taking care of each element representing different things, like products?

Then, we can send to Google Analytics not just an event name each time an element is part of the DOM, but an event parameter as well, with the product ID. This will allow us to create reports in analytics, asking not only how many times a product appears as part of pages, but to refine the question: "How many times X product appears across pages?".

Altering steps 1-4 to contemplate events attributes, that can be done in a beautiful way. If anyone is interested, I am open to sharing this alternative as well.